# Devise Invitable

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-invitable

I am trying to refresh the invitations page when an admin sends out an invite (instead of redirecting to the root path).  The Devise Invitable documentation says:

> After an invitation is created and sent, the inviter will be
>   redirected to after_invite_path_for(inviter, invitee), which is stored
>   path or the same path as after_sign_in_path_for by default.

However how exactly do I incorporate this in to my app?  I have it set up where an admin invites a user.

Here is my invitations controller:

```
class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController



  def new
    super
  end        

  def create
    super
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I added the following to my application controller

def after_invite_path_for(resource)
  new_user_invitation_path
end